# Pointwise convergence of stopped uniformly convergent functions

Tags: analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f,f_n:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be continuous for $n\in\mathbb N$ with $$\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}|f_n(s)-f(s)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0,\tag1$$ $C\ge0$, $$\tau_n:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:|f_n(t)|\ge C\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ and $$\tau:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:|f(t)|\ge C\right\}$$ with the convention $\inf\emptyset=\infty$.

> How can we show that $$f_n(\tau_n\wedge t)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}f(\tau\wedge t)\tag2\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0,$$ where $x\wedge y:=\min(x,y)$?

Let $$g_n(t):=\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}|f_n(s)|\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $$g(t):=\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}|f(s)|\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$ Let's consider the case $0<\tau<\infty$. [We can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812474/if-f0-infty-to-mathbb-r-is-continuous-and-tau-inf-left-t-ge0f-ge-v) that $$|f(\tau)|=C\tag3.$$ By the reverse triangle inequality and $(1)$, $$|g_n(\tau)-g(\tau)|\le\sup_{s\in[0,\:\tau]}|f_n(s)-f(s)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag4.$$ Let $\varepsilon>0$. By $(3)$ and $(4)$, there is a a $N\in\mathbb N$ with $$|g_n(\tau)-C|<\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }n\ge N\tag5.$$ My hope is that we can somehow conclude $\tau_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\tau$ from $(5)$, but I wasn't able to figure out how.

Comment: You need not have $\tau_n \to \tau$. Consider $f(t) = \min \{ t, C\}$ and $f_n(t) = \bigl(1 - 2^{-n}\bigr)\cdot f(t)$. But you can conclude $\liminf \tau_n \geqslant \tau$, and that suffices.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you elaborate your solution?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It doesn't suffice to prove $(2)$, since that doesn't necessarily hold ($f_n(\tau_n \wedge t)$ need not converge, and if it converges it can also converge to $-f(\tau \wedge t)$). It suffices to show that $(2)$ holds for $t \leqslant \tau$, but for $t > \tau$ bad things can happen.

Comment: @DanielFischer 1. Why does it suffice to show $(2)$ for $t\le\tau$? 2. So, you think that the claim is wrong in general?

Comment: Sorry, that was expressed in an unclear way. $\liminf \tau_n \geqslant \tau$ suffices to show $f_n(\tau_n\wedge t) \to f(\tau \wedge t)$ for $t \leqslant \tau$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, okay. Could you prove that? And you didn't answer my second question: Do you think that the claim is wrong for $t>\tau$ or do you simply don't know it?

Comment: And yes, the claim is wrong in general. Consider $$f(t) = \begin{cases}  C &, 0 \leqslant t \leqslant C \\ 2C - t &, C \leqslant t \leqslant 4C \\ -2C &, t \geqslant 4C\end{cases}$$ and $f_n(t) = (1 - 2^{-n})f(t)$, and look at $t > 3C$. Since $\tau_n \to 3C$, we have $f_n(\tau_n \wedge t) \to -C$, but $\tau = C$ and $f(\tau \wedge t) = C$.

Comment: If $t \leqslant \tau$, then $t_n := \tau_n \wedge t \to t$, so $f_n(t_n) \to f(t)$ by locally uniform convergence.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm, I've found the claim in a [paper (Lemma 4.3)](http://bibos.math.uni-bielefeld.de/preprints/05-08-192.pdf) in a slightly different way: Therein they take a fixed $T>0$ and consider $f,f_n:[0,T]\to\mathbb R$ with $f_n\to f$ uniformly. They define $\tau:=\inf\left\{t\in[0,T]:|f_n(t)|\ge C\right\}\wedge T$ and $\tau_n$ in the same way. Now, they claim that $f_n(\tau_n\wedge T)\to f(\tau\wedge T)$. However, that should be the same claim as in the question.

Comment: That doesn't change much, still wrong as written. I have no idea how much of the paper that affects, but "oops".